# Time gap between Two tasks in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am inserting data to hive table with iterations in spark.

For example :  Lets say 10 000 items, firstly these items are separated to 5 list, each list has 2000 items. After that I am doing iteration on that 5 lists.

In each iteration, 2000 items maps to much more rows so at the end of iteration 15M records are inserted to hive table. Each iteration is completed in 40 mins.

Issue is after each iteration. spark is waiting for starting the other 2000 K items. The waiting time is about 90 mins ! In that time gap, there is no active tasks in spark web UI below. 
[image]

By the way, iterations are directly start with spark process. no any scala or  java code is exist at the begging or at the end of iterations.

Any idea?

Thanks

```
   val itemSeq = uniqueIDsDF.select("unique_id").map(r => r.getLong(0)).collect.toSeq // Get 10K items
  val itemList =  itemSeq.sliding(2000,2000).toList // Create 5 Lists


itemList.foreach(currItem => {

//starting code. (iteration start)
        val currListDF = currItem.toDF("unique_id")

        val currMetadataDF = hive_raw_metadata.join(broadcast(currListDF),Seq("unique_id"),"inner")
        currMetadataDF.registerTempTable("metaTable")
        // further logic here ....
   }
```

Comment: May be an idea to share some code.

Comment: I added the main logic of code. I am doing some more steps in iteration. at the end of it. I inserting results to hive table. After insert step is completed, the new iteration is waiting for about 90 mins. You can see the time gap in screen shot.

Comment: @baris : check my answer hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I got the reason, even if the insert task seems completed in spark ui, in background insert process still continue. After writing to hdfs is completed,  new iteration  is starting. That is the reason for gap in web ui

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I understand that you are trying to divide `DataFrame` and pass the data in batches and do some processing as your pseudo code, which  was not so clear.

> As you mentioned above in your answer, when ever action happens it
>   will take some time for insertion in to sink.

But basically, what I feel your logic of `sliding` can be improved like this...

---

Based on that above assumption, I have 2 options for you. you can choose most suitable one...

***Option #1:(`foreachPartitionAsync` : [AsyncRDDActions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.AsyncRDDActions))*** 
  I would suggest you to use `DataFrame` iterator grouping capabilities

```
 df.repartition(numofpartitionsyouwant) // numPartitions
    df.rdd.foreachPartitionAsync  // since its partition wise processing to sink it would be faster than the approach you are adopting...
        { 
partitionIterator =>
          partitionIterator.grouped(2000).foreach {
        group => group.foreach {
        // do your insertions here or what ever you wanted to ....
        }
       }
      }
```

**Note :** RDD will be executed in the background. All of these executions will be submitted to the Spark scheduler and run concurrently. Depending on your Spark cluster size that some of the jobs may wait until Executors become available for processing.

***Option #2 :***

Second approach is dataframe as [randomSplit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html) I think you can use in this case to divide equal sized dataframes. which will return you equal sized array of dataframes if sum of their weights > 1
Note : weights(first argument of dataframe) for splits, will be normalized if they don't sum to 1.

> DataFrame[]   randomSplit(double[] weights) Randomly splits this
>   DataFrame with the provided weights.

refer `randomSplit` code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala)

it will be like ..

```
val equalsizeddfArray =  yourdf.randomSplit(Array(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2, 0.3) // intentionally gave sum of weights > 1 (in your case 10000 records of dataframe to array of 5 dataframes of each 2000 records in it)
```

and then...

```
for (i <- 0 until equalsizeddfArray.length) {
  // your logic ....
}
```

***Note*** : 
Above logic is sequential... 
If you want to execute them in parallel (if they are independent) you can use

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

`// Now wait for the tasks to finish before exiting the app`  `Await.result(Future.sequence(Seq(yourtaskfuncOndf1(),yourtaskfuncOndf2()...,yourtaskfuncOndf10())), Duration(10, MINUTES))`

Out of above 2 options, I would prefer approach #2 since randomSplit function will take care(by normalizing weights) about dividing equal sized to process them

Comment: any questions around this ? pls feel free to ask